# Convert TextEditingController in Flutter to double

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the type of `TextEditingController` to a double so I can make arithmetic calculation .

Example :

```
final value1 = TextEditingController();
final value2 = TextEditingController();
```

Function :

```
double sum ( value1,value2) { 
return value1 - value2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse it first into double then do your calculations

```
double sum ( TextEditingController value1, TextEditingController value2) { 
   return double.parse(value1.text) - double.parse(value2.text);
}
```